# MySQL query not showing with LEFT JOIN and multiple AND clauses

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I added the line AND `t.cover='$c'` and now it will not show any results. However, all variables are correct.  If I run the line in phpMyAdmin it will display the results fine.  Am I missing syntax in PHP?  If I remove the `t.cover='$c'` the script works fine on the web.  `$c` is simply a `$_GET['c']` that will either be empty or will equal 0, which I redefine to 'No'.

```
if($t != '') {
    if($c == 'No') {
         $getListings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events t LEFT JOIN bars b on t.venue=b.name WHERE t.date='$date' AND t.type='$t' AND t.cover='$c' AND b.active='1' ORDER BY t.promoted DESC, t.order ASC");
    } else {
         $getListings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events t LEFT JOIN bars b on t.venue=b.name WHERE t.date='$date' AND t.type='$t' AND b.active='1' ORDER BY t.promoted DESC, t.order ASC");
    }
} else {
     if($c == 'No') {
          $getListings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events t LEFT JOIN bars b on t.venue=b.name WHERE t.date='$date' AND t.cover='$c' AND t.type='$t' AND b.active='1' ORDER BY t.promoted DESC, t.order ASC");
     } else {
          $getListings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events t LEFT JOIN bars b on t.venue=b.name WHERE t.date='$date' AND b.active='1' ORDER BY t.promoted DESC, t.order ASC");
     }
}
```

My biggest confusion is why it works in phpMyAdmin but yet displays no rows on the web.

It seems I have tried everything on Google and still no luck.  I wish it would throw an error or something to point me in a direction, but it just comes up as though the query was empty.  If anyone has any idea, I am still looking for input.  Maybe LEFT JOIN is doing it?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know much about PHP, but when I hear that it works once place vs another, I immediately think that this my be a permissions problem. What user are you logged in as from phpMyAdmin vs the website?

Comment: Could you print out the query to see what $c actually is?

Comment: @Poodlehat, the query works on the web until he adds the AND t.cover = 'c$' clause.

Comment: Printing out the query points correctly to 'No' if it is set, if not it would fall back to the else.  When I remove the AND t.cover='$c' is when for some reason the whole query just falls as though no fields match.  But I run the SAME query in phpMyAdmin and it pulls up results.

Answer (score 1):

...`LEFT JOIN bars b on t.venue=b.name AND b.active=1` ...
Remove the b.active from the WHERE otherwise it will be a condition for the SELECT

The current queries have `SELECT... WHERE ... b.active = 1 ...` meaning it can only return results where that condition is met

Comment: Like this:
`SELECT * FROM events t LEFT JOIN bars b on t.venue=b.name AND b.active='1' WHERE t.date='$date' AND t.type='$t' AND t.cover='$c' ORDER BY t.promoted DESC, t.order ASC`

if so, still no luck.  I have never been this stumped on something, and I cannot find anything online that is similar to my issue.  And again the syntax working in phpMyAdmin is really boggling my mind.